# Failed to open a file with pickle

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, pickle

I've saved a dictionary of dictionaties of pairs of pandas timestamps in the pickle file with

```
  pickle.dump(doublesplit_list, open( "doublesplit_list.p", "wb" ))
```

Then I tried to use

```
    doublesplit_list = pickle.load(open('doublesplit_list.p', 'rb'))
```

And then I got

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 doublesplit_list = pickle.load(open('doublesplit_list.p', 'rb'))

File D:\Porgrams\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx:132, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._unpickle_timestamp()

TypeError: _unpickle_timestamp() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (4 given)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

From what the error message says, the error occurs in `\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx` at line 132 in the definition of `_unpickle_timestamp()` and the error message for you reads that it takes exactly 3 positional args but 4 were given.

However, from the GitHub repo: that particular [line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/178e504c90ef2cfb6e2dccf5b409c3787e0a3bbe/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L167) is:

```py
def _unpickle_timestamp(value, freq, tz, reso=NPY_FR_ns):
```

which does indeed take 4 args so you shouldn't have seen an error like that where it says that function takes exactly 3 args. Even if there was more args passed to it than it should have, the error message should've read like `TypeError: _unpickle_timestamp() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments (... given)`

I suggest checking that particular file in your local machine and see if it matches with what is in the GitHub repo. It could be a compatibility issue with a previous version.